# how to build gmail like menu header

Tags: javascript, html, css, gmail

how can i build fixed menu like gmail menu. i have tried css, but the div stays in middle, it doesnt come up like the gmail menu does on scroll.

[open in large image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hi3N.png)
[image: gmail menu scroll effect]

i have tried using css property, following is some example code (not real code):

```
.menu {
    position:fixed;
    height: 36px;
    background-color:#fff;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Position fixed alone is not enough to achieve this effect. Also, `position:fixed` does not work in IE7 or below, so you'll probably want to have fallback.

You need to use javascript (jQuery makes it easy) to dynamically change the position of the element based upon how far scrolled down the page you are.

Look into `.scrollTop()`

http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/

```
var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use javascript to check the scrollTop and set the position of your menu to fixed if if the scrollTop is more than the height of your header.

```
    function getScrollTop() {
        if(typeof pageYOffset!= 'undefined') {
            //most browsers
            return pageYOffset;
        }
        else {
            var b = document.body; //IE 'quirks'
            var d = document.documentElement; //IE with doctype
            d = (d.clientHeight) ? d : b;
            return d.scrollTop;
        }
    }

    function onScroll() {
        var menu = document.getElementById('divMyMenu');
        var headerAndNavHeight = document.getElementById('divHeader').clientHeight
            + document.getElementById('tsMain').clientHeight;

        if (getScrollTop() < headerAndNavHeight) {
            menu.style.top = headerAndNavHeight + 'px';
            menu.style.position = 'absolute';
        }
        else {
            menu.style.top = '0px';
            menu.style.position = 'fixed';
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

A good and easy to use jQuery Plugin for this is [Waypoints](http://imakewebthings.github.com/jquery-waypoints/)

Here you can see a working example:
http://imakewebthings.github.com/jquery-waypoints/sticky-elements/

Answer (score 0):

May be this is what you are looking for
http://blog.geotitles.com/2011/10/creating-top-fixed-menu-bar-with-css3-buttons-found-in-gmail/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simple trick to implement your requirement explained with example and a link to download.
http://itswadesh.wordpress.com/2012/02/24/google-like-top-bar-with-drop-down-menu-using-html-css-and-jquery/